# Fabric beta not showing Launched event

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I have integrated Fabric using cocoapods like

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics’
```

I'm unable to get the Launched event on Beta section of Fabric. I'm getting this notification on the side:
[image: SDK error]

Also I'm unable to find this "2.2.7" SDK of fabric. My cocoapod shows

```
Crashlytics (3.8.4):
    - Fabric (~> 1.6.3)
- Fabric (1.6.11)
```

I found this link & this is the exact same issue I'm facing. https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-does-not-track-launches-does-not-show-update-on-ios/71188
Does somebody else face the same issue?
This is how I initiate Fabric on the 1st line of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

`[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and It works fine for me.

```
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setDebugMode:YES];
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit, TwitterKit]];
```